# How do I get to innerexception visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have some exceptions in my code that I want to view details about them. I want to get to `InnerException`. I read about View Details in Unhandled Exception dialog box, but it doesn't exist in vs 2013 and about Local Window that I don't know how to open it. How can I do one of them in visual studio 2013?

Comment: *Debug -> Windows -> Locals* while your app is running to get the Locals window. And VS2013 does have the *View Details* option in the unhandled exceptions dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try
{
//Your code
}
catch(Exception ex){ MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.ToString()); }
```

Comment: I can't do this, because I create the file in app.xaml.cs. I added try catch blocks, but I get System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException, not the InnerException

Comment: Maybe [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13638.troubleshooting-wpf-debugging-wpf.aspx) helps you.
**Topic:**
Application.DispatcherUnhandledException

Answer (score 0):

When you capture the exception in the catch block, you can view the exception.InnerException value if it is not null.  This can also be done in the Watcch window.